# Is there a word for a limited term of employment for a specific project?

Tags: phrase-request

I am looking for a word or term for the concept of being employed only for a specific project.

In my native language, we have a word that just means "project employment", it is commonly used to describe the kind of employment where one has a set period of time in the contract, and where one is only expected to work on this very specific project. The contract may even not have a set end date, but instead, stipulate "until the project is done". But it is always a limited time employment.

It is commonly used as a way in on the job market, as if the circumstances allow it, one could be hired for a permanent place after the period ends.

What would the correct English term for this kind of employment for use in my resume/curriculum vitae be?

Comment: What about "temporary worker", but I'm not sure if that fits. By the way, "temporary" seems to be a great adjective in this context.

Comment: Hmm, maybe, but is it a standard term for the thing I'm describing? If not, I'd maybe rather just write project employment.

Comment: As you hinted, a "contract employee".

Answer (score 1):

I have now learned that the correct term is **contract engagement**, at least according to someone I know who works in the automotive industry in Europe.